# Indifferent result when Importing Worksheet from Binaries using PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to get data from a worksheet (not generated by me). It's fetching only 2 rows (including headers) when I import using

```
Excel.Workbook([Content]){[Item="SheetName",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data])
```

Although if I open the file and just save the workbook in my machine it fetches all the rows. Can anyone help me with this indifferent behavior?

Comment: Cross posted: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/607b1da6-24e2-41e7-bd19-ae7e5144ded8/indifferent-result-when-importing-worksheet-from-binaries?forum=powerquery

Comment: Are you able to share copies of the workbook before and after saving the file? My first guess is that some tool is generating the workbook file in a format that's not quite the same as the way Excel formats it.

Comment: thank you for your reply. @CarlWalsh
i cannot share the workbooks here, but i feel the problem is as you've suggested. I'm trying to get hold of the support team of the app that is generating the file, will update as and when i get a reply.

Comment: @Aman if you can generate a workbook with a few rows of dummy data that reproduces the problem, that should be enough :)

Comment: @CarlWalsh on it.

Comment: @CarlWalsh is probably right! I've seen such an issue with Excel spreadsheets exported from SAP. The MS SQL Server didn't recognize data until a file was opened and re-saved in Excel.